# XML Attribute Uniqueness

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to enforce unique attributes. I have read a lot of guides and tried a lot of configurations but I just can't seem to get it.I have used two different validators, XML Copy Editor and http://www.xmlvalidation.com/. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the xml that is considered valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stuff xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com test.xsd">
  <thing att="hi">
    <test>Hi</test>
  </thing>
  <thing att="hi">
    <test>Hi</test>
  </thing>
</stuff>
```

Here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="stuff">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="thing" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="att" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:unique name="thing">
        <xs:selector xpath="thing"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@att"/>
      </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You could try XML Notepad, a free download from Microsoft. This seems a stupidly simple tool, similar to the stupid Notepad editor, but in fact it is very sophisticated and can do a lot of useful validations.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure how that would help. I have a validator that works. I think I don't understand how to properly use unique.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a validating parser? The default in many tools is non-validating. How are you performing the parse?

Comment: I am 100% sure. It catches other schema errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate your XML document correctly, you have to do the following:

1. Move `xs:unique` declaration to `stuff` element declaration (`thing` element doesn't have a child element named `thing`;  the XPath expressions are relative to the parent element).
2. Use a namespace prefix (don't use default namespace when you want to use XPath in XSD).

Your XSD should be rewritten as follow:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
        xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">


<xs:element name="stuff">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="thing" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="att" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>

                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="thing">
            <xs:selector xpath="p:thing"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@att"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```